# Can't mount exfat SD Card

Tags: 16.04, partitioning, mount, exfat

I have some problem recently, after upgrade to Ubuntu 16.04 I can't read my exfat SD Card anymore.

I double checked, got `exfat-fuse` and `exfat-utils` installed, and when I check devices I can see my SD Card as `/dev/sdd`. However when I try to mount it manually it says error:

```
$ sudo mount -t exfat /dev/sdd /media/exfat
FUSE exfat 1.2.3
ERROR: failed to read boot sector.
```

Comment: More specifically, `/dev/sdd` is the raw storage device while the file system is typically and likely on one of the partitions on that device, often the first partition which is located at `/dev/sdd1`. You can also use a GUI application to mount exfat file systems (e. g. Nautilus or Gnome Disks).

Answer (score 0):

Your SD card is probably partitioned. Run `sudo fdisk -l /dev/sdd` to see this. If it's partitioned, then replace the device with the partition (e.g, `/dev/sdd1`) in your mount command.